# kotlin geneirc with vararg parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection, variadic-functions

Now I am working on some problems about passing the function as parameter in a function with vararg parameter with generic parameter. The below code works for one function as parameter into other

function like that funA(funB(parameter):return1):return2

but when i make function like that

funA(vararg funB(parameter):return1):return2

it doesn't works. I have tried somethings like Array  or KFunction1

**ViewModel**

```
fun callMultipleAPI( vararg  observable: Observable<Any>):LiveData<Boolean>{
.....
return progressDialogData!!
}

fun callGetTeammateListAPITEST():Observable<Any>{
....
return repo.callGetMessageSumTEST()!!
}
```

**Fragment**

```
fun test(){
EasyDialog<Observable<Any>,LiveData<Boolean>>(ctx, true,viewModel!!::callGetTeammateListAPITEST,recallFunctionWithFunction = viewModel!!::callMultipleAPI).createNativeNetworkDialog2()
}
```

EasyDialog

```
class EasyDialog<T,V> {
var canCancel: Boolean = true
var recallFunction: (() -> T)? = null
var recallFunctionWithValue: ((value: T) -> Unit)? = null
var context: Context? = null
var value: T? = null
var functionPara :(()->T)? = null
var recallFunctionWithFunction:((T) -> V)? = null



constructor(
context: Context?, canCancel: Boolean, value: ()->T, recallFunctionWithFunction:  (T) -> V  ){
this.context = context
this.canCancel = canCancel
this.functionPara = value
this.recallFunctionWithFunction = recallFunctionWithFunction
}

fun createNativeNetworkDialog2() {
...

    functionPara?.let{ functionPara->{ recallFunctionWithFunction?.let {
            recallFunctionWithFunction-> compose<T,V>(recallFunctionWithFunction  ,functionPara).invoke()
    }}}
}

}

    fun <T, V> compose( f: (T) -> V,    g:() -> T ): () -> V {
            return {  f(g()) }
}
```

But it only allow the function without vararg parameter. 
I try to  make something out as below

```
var functionPara :(()->T)? = null
var recallFunctionWithFunction:( (Array<out T>) -> V)? = null
    constructor(
    context: Context?, canCancel: Boolean, value: ()->T, recallFunctionWithFunction:   (Array<out T>) -> V  ){
    this.context = context
    this.canCancel = canCancel
    this.functionPara = value
    this.recallFunctionWithFunction = recallFunctionWithFunction
}
    fun <T, V> compose( f: (Array<out T>)->V,   vararg g:() -> T ): () -> V {

        return {  f(g()) }
}
```

but it shows the type mismatch

[type Mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSsMT.png)

can anyone help?

Comment: format your code, it is impossible to read, Or better [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have made it clear. Thanks

Comment: can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `g` is an array of functions. Not a function. Looks like you have call all these functions and collect the results:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T, V> compose(crossinline f: (Array<out T>) -> V, vararg g: () -> T): () -> V {
    val results = g.map { it() }
    return { f(results.toTypedArray()) }
}
```

You have to mark your function as `inline` if want to use arrays here

Comment: After I use your function, it shows the error like that [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3k3A.png) After that, i change the list<out T> to Array<out T > in compose function it beings like that [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCas4.png) what should i do?

Comment: do you really need `Array` instead of `List`?

Comment: this is bacause the function recallFunctionWithFunction with vararg parameter will automatically cast to Array<out T> ->V

Comment: If i change all Array<out T to  List < out T  in EasyObserver, the fragment will report the mismatch error  like that [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWBn1.png)

Comment: yep, I'm just interesting: why someone uses `Array` instead of `List` in Kotlin?

Comment: Thanks, after i change the compose like that there are another error show that i didn't seen before . Sorry i am a beginner in this way  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKe0a.png)

Comment: still stuck in there

Comment: ah, I didn't notice it. So from my point of view, you cannot use arrays here. It should be pretty easy to convert it to list

Comment: that means use list instead of array in the compose function?
sorry i have no idea what to do,i can not use the compose function 
like this      [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKe0a.png)

Comment: can anyone help?