# kotlin reference function with vararg parameter and convert Array<out to List<out

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, reflection, variadic-functions

I have asked the question based on this topic 
[Base Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62260177/kotlin-geneirc-with-vararg-parameter)

So, i want to ask in advanced.
With someone answered the question with Array and List

```
Class Test<T,V>{
   var functionPara :(()->T)? = null
   var recallFunctionWithFunction:( (Array<out T>) -> V)? = null

   constructor(value: ()->T, recallFunctionWithFunction:   (Array<out T>) -> V  ){
   this.functionPara = value
   this.recallFunctionWithFunction = recallFunctionWithFunction
}
inline fun <reified T, V> compose(crossinline f: (Array<out T>) -> V, vararg g: () -> T): () -> V {
val results = g.map { it() }
return { f(results.toTypedArray()) }
}

fun <T, V> compose(f: (List<out T>) -> V, vararg g: () -> T): () -> V {
val results = g.map { it() }
return { f(results) }
}
}
fun runCompose(){
compose(functionPara,recallFunctionWithFunction).invoke()
}
```

But i discovered that When i reference a function with vararg parameter like that

```
fun functionA(vararg :Observable<Any>):LiveData<Boolean>{
}
fun functionB():Observable<Any>{
}
```

When i do something like ::functionA  the type of A will be `Array<out Observable<Any>>->LiveData<Boolean>` Therefore , when i do something like that

`Test<Observable<Any>,LiveData<Boolean>>(::functionB,::functionA).runCompose()`

***Situation 1***
If I use the compose function with accepting List type it will show type mismatch due to referencing ::functionA  will return Array

[image: Image1]

***Situation 2***
If i use the compose function with accepting Array type it will show the error

Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead

[image: Image2]

In previous post , some answered me that convert the array to list. But how to convert reference  function with vararg parameter with Originally `Array<out to List <out` ??
when i reference a function like ::function  the type must be `Array<out`
but i want to plug it into compose function. I must convert it.
Can anyone help?  i stuck in there long days. Hope someone can save me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert a list to a typed array because of types erasure. I think the easiest way is to use `List` everywhere.

```
class Test<T, V>(val recallFunctionWithFunction: (List<T>) -> V, val functionPara: () -> T) {

    inline fun compose(crossinline f: (List<T>) -> V, vararg g: () -> T): () -> V {
        return { f(g.map { it.invoke() }) }
    }

    fun runCompose() {
        compose(recallFunctionWithFunction, functionPara).invoke()
    }
}

fun functionA(l: List<Observable<Any>>): LiveData<Boolean> {
...
}
fun functionB(): Observable<Any> {
...
}
```

Another solution

```
class Test<T, V>(
    val recallFunctionWithFunction: (Array<out T>) -> V,
    val functionPara: () -> T,
    val clazz: Class<T>
) {

    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T, V> create(
            noinline recallFunctionWithFunction: (Array<out T>) -> V,
            noinline functionPara: () -> T
        ) = Test(recallFunctionWithFunction, functionPara, T::class.java)
    }

    inline fun compose(crossinline f: (Array<out T>) -> V, vararg g: () -> T): () -> V {
        return {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            val arr = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, g.size) as Array<T>
            g.forEachIndexed { index, fg -> arr[index] = fg.invoke() }
            f(arr)
        }
    }

    fun runCompose() {
        compose(recallFunctionWithFunction, functionPara).invoke()
    }
}

...
val t = Test.create(::functionA, ::functionB)
t.runCompose()
```

Comment: it is not works. Because when i call Test<Observable<Any>,LiveData<Boolean>>(::functionB,::functionA).runCompose() the :: functionB  is Array<out Observable<Any>>>-->LiveData<Boolean>    not a list , the function reference with vararg is Array <out  not List<out

Comment: @yuk as i said, use List instead of varargs and arrays, in `functionA` too. Also added another solution

Comment: it works!!!! thanks a lot  but i consider if there are easier way